# May I declare the *shape outside the for loop?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *shapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *object in array) {
    NSString *type = [object objectForKey:@"Type"];
    ShapeFactory *shape = [[[ShapeFactory alloc] init] shapeWithType:type dictionary:object];
    [shapes addObject:shape];
}
self.shapes = shapes;
```

I want to know if i can declare the variable *shape outside the loop and still work

Comment: Yes, you can declare `shape` outside the loop but there is no reason to. Your posted code is the preferred way to write that code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of: Yes, as Roee84 said, this is valid syntax and you can do that. However, the fact that you have (deducing from the method name) a factory class pattern here and the type of the created shape seems to be defined by a special argument, I wonder why you're using `ShapeFactory`. Why not simply use `id`?
The array won't care about the object and it's probably better to not pretend the objects are of the same type as the factory class object.

That being said, your code is correct. Of course, you can *also* declare `shape` (the `*` is usually considered part of the type, btw) outside of the loop. You don't even need to declare a local mutable array (assuming your property is also a mutable array). I'll use `id` in this example just to illustrate what I said above:

```
self.shapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
id shape; // only declaration! note no * as id is basically NSObject *
for (NSDictionary *object in array) {
    NSString *type = [object objectForKey:@"Type"];
    shape = [[[ShapeFactory alloc] init] shapeWithType:type dictionary:object];
    [self.shapes addObject:shape];
}
```

If your property is not a mutable array, you can't do `self.shapes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`, etc., of course, but then I'd suggest being completely safe with the last line and write `self.shapes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:shapes]`. This may seem a bit paranoid, but that way you're not just casting the mutable object to an immutable one, you actually *have* an immutable one (I'm writing libraries often and sometimes I have to expect users trying to be... frisky with stuff... ^^). Then it can't be mutated behind your back.

Comment: Huh? What was that downvote for? It seemed Ionut Branzei was new to Objective-C so I tried to provide an answer that's a little more explanatory. Is anything with my code wrong or misleading?

Answer (score 0):

Shapes should be declared outside the loop.
Shape is declared inside the loop, since you want to iterate every object.
So what you did is fine.

Comment: but how? i don't have the *type and *dictionary outside the loop @Roee84

Comment: If shape is depends on the object, it's supposed to inside the loop. If all the shapes has the same type and dictionary you can do it outside the loop.